# Python: search for html tag starting with characters

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to find a tag with class "product-category".

```
soup0.findAll("a",{"class":"product-category"})
```

How do i write if I need to find a tag whose class starts with product-category.
I tried using

```
soup0.findAll("a",{"class":%"product-category"}) ##This doesnt work.
```

Is there any way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you can do something like so:

```
import re
tagsStartingWithB = soup.findAll(re.compile('^b'))
[tag.name for tag in tagsStartingWithB]
# [u'body', u'b', u'b']
```

See more [here.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs))